# How to extract xml data to a list of Map of Strings?

Tags: java, xml, binding

I have an xml data like this

```
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <books>
     <book>
       <name>SCJP</name>
       <author>Kathy Sierra</author>
       <publisher>Tata McGraw Hill</publisher>
       <isbn>856-545456736</isbn>
     </book>
     <book>
       <name>Java Persistence with Hibernate</name>
       <author>Christian Bauer</author>
       <publisher>Manning</publisher>
       <isbn>978-3832180577</isbn>
     </book>
   </books>`
```

Is there a way to to convert this xml data to List<Map<String,String>> or List<Map<String,Object>>
with out using a class? .Please help. Thanks

I have tried to extract this with java code using JAX unmarshalling ,

https://ibytecode.com/blog/jaxb-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-of-objects/,

which is working for me and i am getting results like

```
  [Book [name=SCJP, author=Kathy Sierra, publisher=Tata McGraw Hill, isbn=856-545456736], 
  Book [name=Java Persistence with Hibernate, author=Christian Bauer, publisher=Manning, isbn=978-  3832180577]]
```

I am only expecting

[{name="SCJP", author="Kathy Sierra", publisher="Tata McGraw Hill", isbn="856-545456736"},
{name="Java Persistence with Hibernate", author="Christian Bauer", publisher="Manning", isbn="978-  3832180577"}]

Comment: How does List<Map<String,String>> relate to your XML data exactly?

Comment: I am just asking if there is a way to convert xml data to list of Map of Strings.

Comment: You could fill your `List`/`Map` using Java's StAX (via javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader) or DOM (via javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder).

Comment: I have three other files to convert, i cannot use a keyword from dom to extract the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XQuery 3.1, using the Saxon API, run the query

```
/books/book ! map:merge(* ! map{local-name(.) : string(.)})
```

This will return an `XdmValue` which can be processed directly in your Java application, or converted to the form you require. To convert it to a `List<Map<String, String>>` you could use

```
List<Map<String, String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (XdmItem item : xdmValue) {
  XdmMap xMap = (XdmMap)item;
  Map<String, String> jMap = new HashMap<>();
  for (XdmAtomicValue key : xMap.keySet()) {
     jMap.put(key.getStringValue(),
              ((XdmAtomicValue)xMap.get(key)).getStringValue();
  }
  list.add(jMap);
}
```

In my view this kind of approach is much more flexible than anything using JAXB, because your application does not have any tight coupling to the XML schema for the data.

You could of course use a different XQuery 3.1 processor such as BaseX, but the API would be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I am new to SAXON and Xquery, but could you please able to tell me how to  connect to the xml data from java code, to get an xdm value, thank you

Comment: There's an overview of the API here: https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!using-xquery/api-query/s9api-query with links to the detail Javadocs.

Comment: Sorry i am unable to do this as i am new to saxon Api, Could you please give me an example?

Comment: That page points to a saxon-resources file which contains a number of examples. But if you're stuck, raise a new question saying exactly what you want to do, and showing your best efforts, and someone will help you.